# How can I update GCC to 5 version if I don't have sudo permits?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install detectron2 (https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/install.html) in conda enviroment (python=3.8.5). I have problems with the compiler:

[image]

And the error I'm getting is the following one:

```
 gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++17’
 error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
 [end of output]
```

And if I do  `gcc --version` I get the following information:

[image]

How can I fix it? I  don't have sudo permits so I don't know how can I install an updated version...

FYI: detectron2 needs GPU but I'm using CPU. But I don't think this is a problem related with the compiler, isn't it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you installed it in your environment? `gxx_linux-64`

Comment: Yes, thanks! The solution finally was:

Comment: ` conda install gcc_linux-64` 
` conda install gxx_linux-64`
`export CC=/home/.conda/envs/orvit9/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gcc `
`export CXX=/home/.conda/envs/orvit9/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-g++`